# Website Payments Pro Payflow - how to change currency in reference transactions

Tags: paypal, transactions

I'm using WPPPF for payments from php back-end and store only a token returned by PayPal after 1st successful transaction.

The problem is that if e.g. original transaction used USD as a currency, I cannot use any other currency for further transactions.

Is it possible to update reference transaction data to use different currency and still use the same token?

Thanks,
Alex